# MathJax issue with Internet explorer 9

Tags: scroll, internet-explorer-9, mathjax

it seems MathJax has a problem when running on IE9.
Go to [this page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/) and scroll down as much as you can. If you are running it on IE9 the page will contine to go down and down after the end of the page. This will not happen on Chrome, firefox and IE10.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: The page renders fine on browserstack http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/97cfa69075ef3400438a2cf7cc761ae133043a7e

Comment: Ok but there is a problem with the behaviour of the scrolling.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce any issues using a fresh copy of Win7